# How can I animate the transformation of one bootstrap glyphicon to another?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-animate

I am using Twitter Bootstrap, Animate.css, and JQuery. I have the following code:

```
<a href="#" id="open-right">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-record" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

When you add the classes "animate fadeOut" or "animate fadeIn" the element will be animated.

What I want to do is when you click that button, glyphicon-record animates out and is replaced with glyphicon-remove-circle. I can get it to go one way, but when I click to go back I want it to change back to the record button and it does not.

This is what I have so far:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#open-right').click(function() {
    $('#open-right span').addClass('animated fadeOut');
    $('#open-right span').removeClass('glyphicon-record animated fadeOut');
    $('#open-right span').addClass('glyphicon-remove-circle animated fadeIn');
    });

})
```

Can someone tell me how to get it to revert back to the original icon, or if there is a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#open-right').click(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass("glyphicon-record")
    {
        $('#open-right span').addClass('animated fadeOut');
        $('#open-right span').removeClass('glyphicon-record animated fadeOut');
        $('#open-right span').addClass('glyphicon-remove-circle animated fadeIn');
    }

    else
    {
        $('#open-right span').addClass('animated fadeOut');
        $('#open-right span').removeClass('glyphicon-remove-circle animated fadeOut');
        $('#open-right span').addClass('glyphicon-record animated fadeIn');
    }

});

});
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the icon doesn't change at all when I click it